# Why does using pointer of a pointer in linked list give me different value of the list head pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, dereference

There are two function that work with my linked list implementation: `AddToTail` and `PrintList`.
`AddTotail` will add node to the tail.`PrintList` will print the first node in the list.

Here is my attempt to implement the idea:

```
#include <iostream>

struct ListNode
{
    int m_nKey;
    ListNode* m_pNext;
};


void AddToTail(ListNode** &pHead, int value)
{
    ListNode* pAdd = new ListNode();
    pAdd->m_nKey = value;
    pAdd->m_pNext = nullptr;

    if(pHead==nullptr)
    {
        pHead = &pAdd;
    }
    else
    {
        ListNode* pTmp = *pHead;
        while(pTmp->m_pNext!=nullptr)
        {
            pTmp = pTmp->m_pNext;
        }
        pTmp->m_pNext = pAdd;
    }
}


void PrintList(ListNode** &pHead) {
  if (pHead==nullptr) return;

  std::cout << (*pHead)->m_nKey << std::endl;
}


int main() {
  ListNode** pHead = nullptr;
  AddToTail(pHead, 1);
  std::cout << (*pHead)->m_nKey << std::endl;
  AddToTail(pHead, 2);
  std::cout << (*pHead)->m_nKey << std::endl;
  PrintList(pHead);
  return 0;
}
```

The output is as such:

```
1
2
-306755624
```

which differs from the expected one:

```
1
1
1
```

The problem is the value of `*pHead` changed either after I added a new node, or in a function.

I think it's because I used reference to a pointer to pointer in my functions. However, if I don`t use references, the`pHead`from`main()` would not be affected by my functions...

Comment: Could you clarify what the question is here?

Comment: I think it's about time you take a step back, and read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: And a small note on the code you show: The pointer-to-pointer is probably not needed. Remove one level and it will be simpler and probably easier to handle and get it all correct.

Comment: This is the first time I ask question on stackoverflow and I am sorry about my bad question.I will try to do it better.

Comment: yr actual request is, "please help me debug my program". Have you tried stepping through yr code with a debugger, you should always start there

Comment: you have a whole level of indirection thats not needed (as some dude says) and is confusing you. Get rid of all those `ListNode **`. You should be dealing with `ListNode*`

Comment: second - it looks like printlist should be recursive, but its not, its only printing the list head

Answer (score 2):

#### The problem:

In your code, you have a `ListNode** pHead = nullptr`, which is a **pointer to a pointer** variable. Now let's see what are you doing with it:

```
AddToTail(pHead, 1);
```

Okay, that seems fine. Your `AddToTail` function expects a pointer to a pointer to `ListNode` and that's exactly what you are giving it! Nothing suspicious so far... But we do not have to look a lof further for what is wrong here...

Taking a better look at your function, we can see that you have:

```
void AddToTail(ListNode** &pHead, int value)
{
    ListNode* pAdd = new ListNode();
    pAdd->m_nKey = value;
    pAdd->m_pNext = nullptr;

    if(pHead==nullptr)
    {
        pHead = &pAdd;
    }

    // the rest of the code...
}
```

And here the things are starting to get dirty... Pay **close** attention to what you just wrote here:

```
pHead = &pAdd;
```

Since you passed `pHead` as a reference, your original variable now points to an object... *that is allocated **on the stack** in the function's scope*. **That is not a good idea!**. As soon as your function `return`s, the chunk of memory that previously was a `pAdd` is **no longer valid for usage!**

#### False assumption:

Wait a second... if the usage of that part of memory is indeed invalid, then why when we call:

```
std::cout << (*pHead)->m_nKey << std::endl;
```

just after the `AddToTail(pHead, 1)`, it gives us the correct number? **My output displayed `1`!**

Yes. Your output displayed exactly what you intended to have in your first node of the list. Why didn't it print some garbage value, if it's invalid to use that memory? Because the stack, which contained that part of memory was not cleared yet.

Keep in mind that the mentioned *part of the memory*, that I am referring to, was a pointer - a simple value that represents an address. That's why as long as this chunk is not cleared, we are able to look at it and deduce where is the object that we really want to point to. As soon as the stack gets cleared, the address becomes a garbage value and are looking at some random value pointed by... some random value. After calling `std::cout << (*pHead)->m_nKey << std::endl` you can see that the stack will be cleared, since if you try to run:

```
std::cout << (*pHead)->m_nKey << std::endl;
std::cout << (*pHead)->m_nKey << std::endl;
```

instead of calling the `std:: << ...` once, the second call would **actually print some garbage value**.

#### What is the solution?

Actually, there are plenty. We are using `C++`, so I see no reason to not implement the list operations as member functions, but let's not change your original code that much. Firstly, let's drop a one level of "*...points to...*", so instead of:

```
ListNode** pHead = nullptr;
```

we are going to have and work with:

```
ListNode* pHead = nullptr;
```

Accordingly, we change our functions:

```
void AddToTail(ListNode* &pHead, int value) // the arguments have changed
{
    ListNode* pAdd = new ListNode();
    pAdd->m_nKey = value;
    pAdd->m_pNext = nullptr;

    if(pHead==nullptr)
    {
        pHead = pAdd; // notice the difference!
    }
    else
    {
        ListNode* pTmp = pHead; // here too!
        while(pTmp->m_pNext!=nullptr)
        {
            pTmp = pTmp->m_pNext;
        }
        pTmp->m_pNext = pAdd;
    }
}
```

Of course, your `PrintList` also needs to be changed, as well as some code in `main()`, but now it's your job to do so. Just to give you some insight, this:

```
ListNode* pHead = nullptr;
AddToTail(pHead, 1);
std::cout << pHead->m_nKey << ' ';
AddToTail(pHead, 2);
std::cout << pHead->m_nKey << std::endl;
```

prints **`1 1`**.

*Post Scriptum: I would **highly** encourage you to change your implementation in such a way that functions, instead of being a free ones, be parts of the `ListNode` class, and maybe use a `node<T>` as a private class inside the mentioned one to increase readability and consistency of the code*

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> void AddToTail(ListNode** &pHead, int value)
> ```

`pHead` is a reference. It refers to a variable that is outside of the function `AddToTail`.

> ```
> ListNode* pAdd = ...
> ```

`pAdd` is an automatic variable in the `AddToTail` function. Automatic variables are destroyed when function returns.

> ```
> pHead = &pAdd;
> ```

You store the address of an automatic variable in the pointer referenced by `pHead`.

> ```
> AddToTail(pHead, 1);
> ```

After `AddToTail` returns, `pHead` points to the local variable that was destroyed. Dereferencing `pHead` will have undefined behaviour, because it doesn't point to an object that's valid.

> ```
> std::cout << (*pHead)->m_nKey << std::endl;
> ```

Here you dereference `pHead` that doesn't point to a valid object. The behaviour is undefined.

Comment: pAdd is an automatic variable in the AddToTail function. Automatic variables are destroyed when function returns.So why pAdd won't destroy when  I am using pHead = pAdd (pHead is a pointer of ListNode)

Comment: @Leslie `pAdd` will be destroyed. But `ListNode* pHead` doesn't point to `pAdd`, so you don't end up dereferencing a pointer to an invalid object.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively could also try something like this:

```
struct ListNode
{
    int m_nKey;
    ListNode* m_pNext;
};


void AddToTail(ListNode **pHead, int value)
{
    ListNode* pAdd = new ListNode();
    pAdd->m_nKey = value;
    pAdd->m_pNext = nullptr;

    if (*pHead == nullptr)
    {       
        *pHead = pAdd;
    }
    else
    {
        ListNode *pTmp = *pHead;
        while (pTmp->m_pNext != nullptr)
        {
            pTmp = pTmp->m_pNext;
        }
        pTmp->m_pNext = pAdd;
    }
}


void PrintList(ListNode *pHead) {
    if (pHead == nullptr) return;

    std::cout << "list key:" << pHead->m_nKey << std::endl;
    PrintList(pHead->m_pNext);
}


int main()
{ 
    ListNode *pHead = nullptr;
    AddToTail(&pHead, 1);
    std::cout << pHead->m_nKey << std::endl;
    AddToTail(&pHead, 2);
    std::cout << pHead->m_nKey << std::endl;
    PrintList(pHead);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I did it before, but I think it is not perfect because I have to do more jobs when I use the list.

Comment: @Leslie I don't understand what you mean. While others suggested passing pointer by reference, this passes pointer by pointer. Otherwise it does the same thing.